# Virtual Webcam Blur Entire Input on MacBook Pro M2 Max Mac OS 13.4.1

Tags: webcam

I am looking for a virtual webcam which can blur the input from the built-in webcam. I just want to blur it just a bit for Zoom. It's not just the background I want blurred--I want my face blurred a bit as well, so defects like wrinkles aren't picked up in such high resolution.

Thanks,
Alia

Comment: You could smear a little Vaseline on the lens. If you use honey, it would add a golden glow. Tissue paper or wax paper, too. Perhaps the easiest would be to just turn off the camera.

Answer (score 0):

To blur your background, you can go to the settings in the top bar (left of the date), Video Effects > Portrait. This will blur your background at the OS level.